# Bind to Dynamic Collection of KeyBindings

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have the following XAML code...

```
<xaml:WindowBase.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="D1" Command="{Binding InputItemAddCommand}" CommandParameter="1"/>
        <KeyBinding Key="D2" Command="{Binding InputItemAddCommand}"  CommandParameter="2"/>
        <KeyBinding Key="D3" Command="{Binding InputItemAddCommand}"  CommandParameter="3"/>
</xaml:WindowBase.InputBindings>
```

If I wanted to add an additional keybinding, say for instance D4, I would need to go in the XAML and add an additional line of code.

I would instead like to expose a collection in my viewmodel and bind to this list...

Something like...

```
 <xaml:WindowBase.InputBindings KeyBindings="{Binding MyKeyBindingCollection}"/>
```

And then populate MyKeyBindingCollection in the viewmodel (I am using the MVVM approach)

```
var MyKeyBindingCollection = new List<KeyBinding>();
MyKeyBindingCollection.Add(new KeyBinding(InputItemAddCommand, Key.D1, ModifierKeys.None));
MyKeyBindingCollection.Add(new KeyBinding(InputItemAddCommand, Key.D2, ModifierKeys.None));
MyKeyBindingCollection.Add(new KeyBinding(InputItemAddCommand, Key.D3, ModifierKeys.None));
```

I don't know if there is something in XAML that would allow me to achieve this or to dynamically populate KeyBindings in the viewmodel.

Any assistance or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you should take a look at the article Matt Hamilton: [`Command Bindings with MVVM`](http://matthamilton.net/commandbindings-with-mvvm).